# How to replace all elements of an ArrayAdapter

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I have to replace all elements of an ArrayAdapter in C# in Monodroid. Here is, how I do it:

```
ArrayAdapter<string> mAdapter;

void ReplaceAllAdapterElements(List<string> aNewElements) 
{
  mAdapter.Clear ();
  foreach(string lElement in aNewElements){
    mAdapter.Add (lElement);
  }  
}
```

Is there any better way doing it ?
In JAVA there is the method AddAll that can add a list of elements to an ArrayAdapter. This method seems to be missing in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Android are you targeting? The [AddAll()](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ArrayAdapter.AddAll%28Java.Lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method on ArrayAdapter is available in Mono for Android, but wasn't added to Android until v3.0. If you update the minimum Android version for your project to 3.1, you should gain access to the method.